# time the pseudo random generator gonna start repeating itself

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

as you know the general formula for  pseudo random generator  is this

```
U(n)=a*U(n−1)+b [mod z]
```

where we have control of `U(n-1)` and `a` and `b` and `z`

i want to know if there is formula that give you how much  generate number  before it start repeating those numbers ?

**E.g**

if we have

- a  = 2
- b  = 5
- U(n-1) = 6
- z  = 26

we have 12 number generated before the sequence start repeating itself

Comment: Do you mean $U_n = aU_{n-1}+b\pmod z$?

Comment: @GregMartin yes you are correct

Comment: @GregMartin any help ?

Answer (score 0):

[Iterated Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function)

Shows the non modulo form has iterates:$$a^nx+\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}b,\quad a\neq1\tag{wikipedia}$$ Which, any time z is odd, can be turned into an equivalent with a and b coprime to z, and we can use Euler's totient theorem to reduce it to x in $\varphi(z)$ iterations. x being our equivalent to Uo . Which if a and b are coprime to z already, also holds for even moduli. Via group theory and Lagranges theorem (I think), then every pair of inputs, will create a cycle that is of length a divisor of this maximal order.

Comment: More specifically, the period of this generator is exactly the same as the multiplicative order of $a$ mod $z$, assuming the two numbers are coprime.

Comment: Okay yes I screwed up (nothing new).